# Clicking the IAP and taking a use to new view

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, ipad, ios4

Hey guys I am trying to figure out this IAP tutorial I would like to just make one simple app with my content instead of flooding the app store with a lot of smaller apps.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

I have been going through this tutorial, I just need someone to help me after the person clicks the check to purchase and the transaction goes through I want it to take them to a new view controller could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't understand where exactly you want to take user to the new view.rather then me going through the full guide can you write in steps what you have done and on which step you want to show new view

Comment: I have everything setup in terms of IAP where users are using a table view and all of the IAP are shown. They click on which IAP they want to buy, as soon as the transaction has gone through it takes them to a new view for example If i was making it a book app and wanted users to have to buy the chapters, once they buy the IAP it takes them to the new view which would be the chapter. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment i believe once the content is purchased then you want to show a new view
So here is the code for that

**1) This is The Main Code for the transaction**

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Since you are checking for successful payment : your case is **SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:**

The following method will be called

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

3) In the **Provide Content** Method you have to show your view :

```
- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productId
{
    if ([productId isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId])//kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId is your IAP id in iTunes Connect
    {
     //Your code goes here;
    }
}
```

Comment: if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.alltrivia.alltrivia.theoffice"])//kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId is your IAP id in iTunes Connect
    {
        -(IBAction)swapViews:(id)sender {
            
            InAppRageAppDelegate *delegate = (InAppRageAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
            [delegate switchView:self.view toView:secondView.view];
            
        }
            
        }
    }

Comment: This is what I'm trying right now to switch the views but I keep getting errors. Is there any easier away to approach this that I am missing?

Comment: What is the errors: put them in your question as an edit. Also Make sure you test your code on your device: IAP doesn't work on simulator. Moreover put break points in your code and check on which line do you get errors